# Complexity of a loop

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, code-complexity

I've just started to learn about data structures and I'd be glad for some help.
Lets say i have this pseudo code of a selection sort function for the A array of numbers:

1. for i = n downto 1 by 1, do
2. maxPos = i
3. for j = i - 1 downto 1 by 1, do
4. if A[ j ] > A[maxPos]
5. maxPos = j
6. swap (A[maxPos], A[ i ])
   I want to calculate the number of steps this function takes.

For what i know so far:
Sentence #1 runs n times (if you calculate the i-- then the number of steps taken in this sentece are 2n)

Sentence #2 runs n - 1 times.

Now for sentence no.3 and onwards is where i'm starting to get confused:
no.3 runs from what I understand $$\sum_{i=1}^(n-1) i$$

Sentence no.4 runs the same amount of steps taken in no.3 only minus 1. That means: $$\sum_{i=1}^(n-1) i -1$$

Sentence no.5 i dont know how to calculate. I mean - for worst case it should be as no.4, and for best case it should be 0. But is it anyway to write it mathematically for any case?

no.6 take the number of steps no.2 takes.

I'd appreciate your help very much. <3

P.s - i know about the Big O cheat sheets and i know the worst case for this function is O($$n^2$$)

P.s no.2 - if anybody knows why mathjax doesnt work here i'd be glad to know what alternatives can i use here.

Comment: The complexity for this particular algorithm will *always* be `O(N^2)`, not just in the worst case, because there is no line of code which will cause a loop to break prematurely or change its conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You have, essentially:

```
for i = n downto 1
    for j = i-1 downto 1
```

The outer loop runs n times. The inner loop runs (n-1) times for the first iteration, (n-2) times for the second iteration, etc. So the number of iterations of the inner loop is:

```
(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)...(n-n)
```

That's basically the [sum of numbers from 1 to n-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), making the asymptotic complexity O(n^2).

See also [Selection sort:Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Complexity).